# How does extension of RAM help in the speed of laptop?

Tags: ram

I have a Asus laptop and it is very slow. It hangs a lot. It is unable to run more than one application at a time. It's specifications are :

Processor : AMD C-60 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.00 GHz
Installed Memory(RAM) : 2.00 GB (1.60 GB usable)
System type : 64-bit Operating System

It's model is X53U and is manufactured in 2012-04.
I want to know that if I extend the RAM will it help? or Could you provide any other suggestion on what is wrong and what can be done to run the applications smoothly?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Komal, welcome to StackOverflow! Typically, questions about general hardware are not supposed to be asked here, as they fall outside the scope of SO. For details on what you can ask, see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Extends the RAM will indeed speed up your computer a little bit and will allow you to launch more applications. 2GB is really a small amount of memory.

However, do not expect to have a beast after your upgrade : Your CPU is quite slow, and can not be changed on a laptop.

If you haven't clean your laptop since 2012-04, dust can also slow down your computer.